# mysql error - Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql

The following query returns results which contains  count greater than 0 i.e, it ignores the records which has no entry in `om.memberid`

```
SELECT id, organizationname, organizationwebsite, renewDate, COUNT( om.memberid ) 
FROM organization o, organizationmember om
WHERE om.organizationid = o.id
GROUP BY o.id
```

Can i get the results whose `count(om.memberid)` is 0  i.e., has no entries in `om.memberid`.

Please suggest me a solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT o.id, o.organizationname, o.organizationwebsite, o.renewDate, COUNT( om.memberid ) 
FROM organization o
LEFT JOIN organizationmember om ON om.organizationid = o.id 
GROUP BY o.id
```